# How do I make multiple combinations with a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

Input should be a string:

```
"abcd@gmail.com"
```

Output should be an Array of strings:

```
["abcd@gmail.com",
 "a.bcd@gmail.com",
 "ab.cd@gmail.com",
 "abc.d@gmail.com",
 "a.b.cd@gmail.com",
 "a.bc.d@gmail.com",
 "a.b.c.d@gmail.com"]
```

The idea: "Make every possible combination in the first string part ("abcd") with a dot. Consecutive dots are not allowed. There are no dots allowed in the beginning and in the end of the first string part ("abcd")"

This is what I've came up with so far:

```
text,s = "abcd".split""
i=0

def first_dot(text)
  text.insert 1,"."
end

def set_next_dot(text)
  i = text.rindex(".")
  text.delete_at i
  text.insert(i+1,".")
end
```

My approach was

1. write a function, that sets the first dot
2. write a function that sets the next dot
3. ...(magic)

I do not know how to put the pieces together. Any Idea? Or perhaps a better way?
thanx in advance

edit:
I think I found the solution :)
I will post it in about one hour (it's brilliant -> truth tables, binary numbers, transposition)

**...and here the solution**

```
s = "abc"
states = s.length
possibilites = 2**states

def set_space_or_dot(value)
  value.gsub("0","").gsub("1",".")
end

def fill_with_leading_zeros(val, states)
  if val.length < states 
   "0"*(states-val.length)+val
  else
   val
  end
end

a = Array.new(possibilites,s)
a = a.map{|x| x.split ""}

b = [*0...possibilites].map{|x| x.to_s(2).to_s}
b = b.map{|x| fill_with_leading_zeros x,states} 
b = b.map{|x| x.split ""}

c = []

for i in 0 ... a.size
  c[i] = (set_space_or_dot (a[i].zip b[i]).join).strip
end
```

Comment: Just asking: Is this a question that may also be tagged with `homework`? ;)

Comment: and what you want to do with this? check if a given email and e.m.a.i.l are the same?

Comment: actually, it is not homework...but it's okay to give it that tag (I am sooo ashamed to ask this question on stackoverflow, I only made an Account for that...)

Comment: @Tiago: removing one or many dots and then performing a check is not a problem in ruby, that's a oneliner ;)

Comment: Don't think that you need to be ashamed for such questions, not everyone is on the same niveau or thinks the same way about solving programming problems.

Answer (score 2):

Changing pduersteler answer a little bit:

```
possibilities = []
string = "abcd@example.com"
(string.split('@')[0].size-1).times do |pos|
  possibility = string.dup
  possibilities << possibility.insert(pos+1, '.')
end
```

Comment: This only generated `["a.bcd@example.com", "ab.cd@example.com", "abc.d@example.com"]`, OP wanted a lot more different version.

Answer (score 1):

How about this (probably needs a bit more fine-tuning to suit your needs):

```
s = "abcd"

(0..s.size-1).map do |i|
  start, rest = [s[0..i], s[(i+1)..-1]]
  (0..rest.size-1).map { |j| rest.dup.insert(j, '.') }.map { |s| "#{start}#{s}"}
end.flatten.compact
#=> ["a.bcd", "ab.cd", "abc.d", "ab.cd", "abc.d", "abc.d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to iterate n times through your string moving the dot, where n is the amount of chars minus 1. This is what you're doing right now, but without defining two methods.

Something like this:

```
possibilities = []
string = "abcd@example.com"
(string.split('@')[0].size-1).times do |pos|
  possibilities << string.dup.insert(pos+1, '.')
end
```

**edit**
Now tested. THanks to the comments, you need to call `.dup` on the string before the insert. Otherwise, the dot gets inserted into the string and will stay there for each iteration causing a mess. Calling `.dup` onthe string will copy the string and works on the copy instead, leaving the original string untouched.

Comment: Great! Thanx. "abcd"-> four characters, "a.b.c.d" -> three dots
(text.length-1).times do set point...
that may work, thanx :)

Comment: this will not work, because [insert](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-insert) changes the string internally.

Comment: `insert` modifies the original stringm but `string.dup.insert` could work for you.

Comment: okay, maybe it is better to let the string "explode" into an Array, seems always better for manipulation...

Comment: thanks for your inputs, wrote the code without possibilities to test it. updating the answer. @BadAssProgrammingnovice doesn't think it is always better to explode a string to an array for manipulation.